# remove unwanted areas which are not inside the boundary of second raster

Tags: qgis, masking

1 raster layer - global map ;
2 raster layer - berlin

I cropped out 1 layer using extent of 2 layer and then overlapped these two layers however I see that 1 layer still has areas apart from berlin(1 layer). What would be the best way to remove those areas and only get the area exact as that of 2 layer?

Also, I tried using  Clipper too but somehow it is not working.

[image: overlapping of two raster layers]

Comment: Have you tried using the **Clipper** tool in _Raster_ > _Extraction_ > _Clipper_?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous question. I did try using Clipper tool but it is not working. @Joseph

Comment: Strange, perhaps try _Raster_ > _Projections_ > _Warp_ and include the second layer as the mask layer?

Comment: I'm not sure why but it takes way too long and ends up with not responding. Thank you tho! @Joseph

Comment: Your welcome @CynicalRealism and apologies, hope you get the results you need!

Answer (score 1):

There is a working Python script solution for this kind of problem. It is available in the Processing toolbox after you downloaded it and placed in the correct folder in your .qgis2 profile directory. It works by extending the boundaries of the input raster using their nodata values. 

[image: http://ssrebelious.wordpress.com]

[Unifying extent and resolution](http://ssrebelious.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/unifying-extent-and-resolution-of-rasters-using-processing-framework-in-qgis/)

As resulting output you will get two matching raster files.

Comment: I'm not sure if i know how to do it since it's only been a while that I started using QGIS, will let you know if it works. Thank you! :) @Curlew